# Injecting multiple clients instead of just one using ASP.NET Core built-in IoC container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-provider

How do I DI multiple clients with multiple API/Secret keys? My current implementation is able to inject only one `BinanceClient` and `BinanceSocketClient` with same API/Secret key.

Is that possible through the built-in IServiceProvider? Something like:

```cs
private readonly IEnumerable<IBinanceClient> _client;
private readonly IEnumerable<IBinanceSocketClient> _socketClient;
```

#### Snippet

```cs
var exchangeOptions = Configuration.GetSection(ExchangeOptions.Exchange).Get<ExchangeOptions>();

services.AddTransient<IBinanceClient, BinanceClient>(_ =>
    new BinanceClient(new BinanceClientOptions
    {
        ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(exchangeOptions.ApiKey, exchangeOptions.SecretKey),
        AutoTimestamp = true,
        AutoTimestampRecalculationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        TradeRulesBehaviour = TradeRulesBehaviour.AutoComply
    }));
services.AddSingleton<IBinanceSocketClient, BinanceSocketClient>(_ =>
    new BinanceSocketClient(new BinanceSocketClientOptions
    {
        ApiCredentials = new ApiCredentials(exchangeOptions.ApiKey, exchangeOptions.SecretKey),
        AutoReconnect = true,
        ReconnectInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
    }));
```

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AlertsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<AlertsController> _logger;
    private readonly IBinanceClient _client;
    private readonly IBinanceSocketClient _socketClient;
    private readonly IAlertService _alertService;

    public AlertsController(ILogger<AlertsController> logger, IBinanceClient client, IBinanceSocketClient socketClient, IAlertService alertService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _client = client;
        _socketClient = socketClient;
        _alertService = alertService;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: The default DI container will allow `IEnumerable<TDependency>` to be injected. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods

Comment: You can add multiple instances of an interface in your setup and inject them into a service by accepting an `IEnumerable` of that interface. For example `IEnumerable<IBinanceClient>` - is that what you meant?

Comment: @DavidG, I think so. How is that gonna work? `services.AddTransient<IEnumerable<IBinanceClient>>`, something like that? The idea is to have multiple and more specifically 3 more API keys `new ApiCredentials(exchangeOptions.ApiKey, exchangeOptions.SecretKey)`

Comment: No, multiple calls to `services.AddTransient<IBinanceClient>(...)`

Comment: @nop add each implementation one at a time like in your original example.

Comment: @Nkosi, can you give an example?

Comment: @nop repeat what you have in your snippet, applying the respective keys as needed for each.

Comment: See the code snippet here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#service-registration-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject multiple versions of a service in your DI setup like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IBinanceClient, BinanceClient>(/* ... config version 1 ... */);
services.AddTransient<IBinanceClient, BinanceClient>(/* ... config version 2 ... */);
services.AddTransient<IBinanceClient, BinanceClient>(/* ... config version 3 ... */);
```

Now in your consuming class, if you had this:

```
public class AlertsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IBinanceClient _client;

    public AlertsController(IBinanceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
}
```

Then the `IBinanceClient` object would contain the most recently added service, in this case, the third version. However, your consuming service can take all of the injected objects like this:

```
public class AlertsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IBinanceClient> _clients;

    public AlertsController(IEnumerable<IBinanceClient> clients)
    {
        _clients = clients;
    }
}
```

Now your consumer will have access to all 3 `IBinanceClient` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much!